# monoid object in "arrows-only" single-sorted definition of a category

Tags: category-theory, monoid

There's a way to define a category as "arrows-only" single-sorted.

An object is an identity morphism : *a → a*

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category

There are Remarks

***Specializations***

> A monoid is a single-sorted category in which *s* is a constant function (hence so is *t*, and they are equal).

So when a monoid object is ***5***, is it expressed like:

*(f → 5)(a → a)*

or simply

*(a → a)(5)*

Thanks.

In Haskell it should be

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ (\f -> 5)(\a -> a)
  print $ (\a -> a)(5)
```

Thanks.

EDIT: to make the problem clearer, I will quote

Categories for the Working Mathematician, I.1 and XII.5.

I.1

[image]

XII.5

[image]

[image]

Comment: In mathematics, one distinguishes between $\to$ and $\mapsto$. The definition of a map is written using $\mapsto$, not $\to$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a category $\mathscr C$ with a single object $X$. Then the one-sorted presentation of $\mathscr C$ will have a collection of morphisms $C = \mathscr C(X, X)$ and functions $s, t : C \to C$ such that $\forall c \in \mathscr C . s(c) = t(c) = \mathrm{id}_X$. That is, $s = t = \lambda c . \mathrm{id}_X$. The composition of morphisms reduces to a binary operation on $C$, because the source and target of each morphism is $\mathrm{id}_X$, and $\mathrm{id}_X$ also acts as an identity for the binary operation. The definition thus reduces exactly to that of a traditional monoid (albeit one with a class of elements, rather than a set of elements, when $\mathscr C$ is not necessarily locally small).

In terms of Haskell, the definition of $s$ and $t$ is therefore given by `\c -> id_X`, for some `id_X`.

Therefore, a one-sorted presentation of a category in Haskell may be described by a [`Monoid`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monoid), which we will call `X`, along with two functions `s :: X -> X` and `t :: X -> X`. `s` and `t` are both defined by `\x -> mempty X`. (Here, [`mempty` is the identity](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monoid) for the monoid.)

```
class Monoid m => OneObjectOneSortedCategory m where
  s :: m -> m
  t :: m -> m
  s _ = mempty
  t _ = mempty

-- An example of a monoid as a one-object single-sorted category.
instance OneObjectOneSortedCategory [a]

main = do
  -- Prints `[]`, the identity element.
  print (s [1, 2, 3])
```

Alternatively, in Rust:

```
trait OneObjectOneSortedCategory: Sized {
    fn id() -> Self;
    
    fn mul(&self, other: &Self) -> Self;
    
    fn s(&self) -> Self {
        Self::id()
    }
    
    fn t(&self) -> Self {
        Self::id()
    }
}

impl OneObjectOneSortedCategory for i8 {
    fn id() -> i8 {
        0
    }
    
    fn mul(&self, other: &i8) -> i8 {
        self + other
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", 5.s());
}
```

---

Since there's still confusion, let me try rephrasing the following quote, which seems to be the issue.

> A monoid is a single-sorted category in which $s$ is a constant function (hence so is $t$, and they are equal).

What does this mean?

If we take a monoid $(M, \otimes, I)$, then we can form a single-sorted category $\mathbf C = M$. The functions $s : \mathbf C \to \mathbf C$ and $t : \mathbf C \to \mathbf C$ are both defined to be the constant function $x \mapsto I$. Therefore, the category $\mathbf C$ has a single object, $I$. The composite $a \circ b$ of two morphisms $a, b \in \mathbf C$ is given by $a \otimes b$. The identity is given by $I \in \mathbf C$.

Alternatively, take a single-sorted one-object category $\mathbf C$. Let $U$ be the object of $\mathbf C$ (i.e. the value of $s(x)$ for any $x \in \mathbf C$). We can define a monoid $(M, \otimes, I)$, where $M = \mathbf C$. Given elements $a, b \in M$, we define their multiplication $a \otimes b := a \circ b$. We define $I := \mathrm{id}_U$.

Therefore, the two presentations are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, however the answer is too abstract, and it's a bit complicated for me to read and understand. Could you please give me a concise example using rather concrete value such as `\a -> a` and `5`?   Also, new line with short sentences helps.

Comment: For instance, in your answer, where are the identity morphisms?

Comment: I've added another sentence, summarising the answer. The idea is that a one-sorted category is exactly the same as a monoid, with two constant functions `s` and `t`. (So `s` and `t` can be ignored, because the data is already given by `mempty`).

Comment: This should be pretty simple, so may I ask you to provide a complete working code? (Just like what I did in my question)

Comment: I know you prefer generalizations in math, but often it's very useful to illustrate a concrete sample to teach learners. A simple code often is better than many words.

Comment: @smooth_writing: sorry, the reason I wasn't being explicit with Haskell is that I'm not overly familiar with Haskell. I've given a small example, including a type class definition. Let me know if this still isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks, so if possible, can you please give me another working code in JavaScript/TypeScript, also Rust should be fine, too. Thanks again!

Comment: @smooth_writing: I've added an example in Rust.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I can study based on your math and codes..

Comment: I have investigated your Rust code in my VS.code, and the result is `0`. I thought `5.s()` was `5`

Comment: Well, I was not asking a way to show some identity value, but since every object is an identity morphism in the definition, I wonder how `5` is obtained throughout the identity.

Comment: @smooth_writing: in what category is `5` an object? What are the morphisms? You need to know what category you're starting with to talk about single objects in them.

Comment: A monoid is a single-sorted category in which s is a constant function (hence so is t, and they are equal). This works up to isomorphism of categories, not merely equivalence, so single-sorted categories may seem to be a more direct oidification of monoids than the usual categories. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category#specializations

Comment: @smooth_writing: in the category of matrices, the object $5$ may be considered a one-object category in which morphisms are $5 \times 5$-matrices. In this setting, if $M$ is a $5 \times 5$-matrix, then $s(M) = t(M) = 5$. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Why don't we the problem simple, let's take an example of natural numbers not matrics.

Comment: @smooth_writing: the objects (i.e. identity morphisms) of the category can be natural numbers, but you need to say what the morphisms are. What does a morphism $5 \to 5$ represent?

Comment: I have edit my question to quote the "arrows-only" definition. Excuse me, but I would like to make sure if you really understand the concept and answer the question.

Comment: Let's make the `identity 1` + `identity 2` = `identity 3`  addition.

Comment: @smooth_writing: you say "So when a monoid object is 5". This doesn't make sense: to define a monoid you need to give a set of elements, a multiplication operation, and an identity. To define a single-sorted one-object category you need to give an object (let's say $5$), a set of morphisms $5 \to 5$, a composition operation, and an identity morphism. In my previous example, the set of morphisms $5 \to 5$ was $(5 \times 5)$-matrices and the composition was multiplication. At the moment, you seem to be confusing the object (i.e. $5$) with the morphisms.

Comment: Right, I understand that and I apologize such a false statement of monoid (set, operation, identity). To avoid confusion, Let's call Identity morphism = object of the "arrow-only" definition as **IDENTITY** , and for monoid identity, let's call **unit**.

Comment: @smooth_writing: I've expanded my answer. I think if this doesn't make sense, I would recommend becoming more familiar with categories and monoids first, and ignoring the single-sorted definition, which is an unusual definition. There's no advantage to the single-sorted definition for programming.

Comment: Thank you for the dedicated answer and comments. I think I had enough information to study. Appreciated!

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to mention it's "unusual" in negative manner because I think one of the source of confusion of Category theory comes from the "usual definition" in the context of "dualism" of objects and arrows which corresponds to set theory.

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/  There is a controversy on this. And I really think "arrows-only" definition should be a standard in Category theory.

Comment: All I meant is that the single-sorted definition is more difficult to understand: it's a clever trick that a category can be described that way, but I'm not sure that it's helpful to use. However, if you like that presentation, the entire book [Categories, Allegories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Categories%2C+Allegories) is written in this style, which you may be interested in.